# SQL Query to get a row, and the count of associated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, like this:

```
#Articles:
ID | Title
1    "Article title"
2    "2nd article title"

#Comments:
ID | ParentID | Comment
1    1          "This is my comment"
2    1          "This is my other comment"
```

I've always wanted to know, what is the most elegant way to get the following result:

```
ID | Title |          NumComments
1    "Article title"      2
2    "2nd article title"  0
```

This is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will normally be faster than the subquery approach, but as always you have to profile your system to be sure:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Title, COUNT(c.ID) AS NumComments
FROM Articles a
LEFT JOIN Comments c ON c.ParentID = a.ID
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Title
```

Comment: dang it you beat me to it... + 1

Comment: Well, first in with the correct answer gets the points! Thanks Joel!

Comment: Count(*) is returning 1 when it should return 0.

Comment: @rixth: actually, David B is correct and there was a bug.  It should be fixed now, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
select title, NumComments = (select count(*) 
from comments where parentID = id) from Articles
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   A.ID, A.Title, COUNT(C.ID) 
FROM 
   Articles AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
   Comments AS C ON C.ParentID = A.ID 
GROUP BY 
   A.ID, A.Title 
ORDER BY 
   A.ID
```

Comment: Ya I know.  Was trying to update and got overwritten.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
select a.ID 'ArticleId',
       a.Title,
       count(c.ID) 'NumComments'
from   Articles a
left join
       Comments c
on     a.ID = c.ParentID
group by a.ID, a.Title
```

This might help in deciding between joining or using sub query:

[Transact-SQL - sub query or left-join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117952/transact-sql-sub-query-or-left-join)

Comment: Small problem with this.  A.ID = C.ID means you will only associate one unique comment to one unique article.  Did you mean A.ParentID=C.ID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
Articles.ID
,Articles.TItle
,(SELECT Count(*) FROM Comments WHERE Comments.ParentId = Artices.ID) AS CommentCount
FROM Articles
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Articles.Title, COUNT(Comments.ID)
FROM Articles INNER JOIN Comments ON Articles.ID = Comments.ParentID
GROUP BY Articles.Title